# What is the difference between fetch() and fetchAll() in PDO query?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm confused with using `fetch()` and `fetchAll` in a PDO statement. I went through the `php.net` manual and that made it more confusing. Even went through the suggestions provided in
stackoverflow.  If anyone could help me understand it the easy way, it would be great.

**For example**

```
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Fetch next row vs fetch all rows? I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: for example: `$sql = "SELECT  column FROM table";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`

Comment: did you also looked to the PHP code and the output examples in the manual for both functions, it's really clear..

Comment: if you want all records .. for fetch you are going to need to loop like `while($row = $stmt->fetch()) { # work with the record }` for `fetchAll()` you have direct acces to the records as a array.

Comment: So fetch returns only 1 value at a time? And fetchAll returns all the values? is that correct.

Comment: *"So fetch returns only 1 value at a time? And fetchAll returns all the values? is that correct"* Yes indeed fetch returns 1 record as a single dimensional array and fetchAll returns all records as a multi dimensional array

Comment: What is so confusing about "PDOStatement::fetch — Fetches the next row from a result set" and "PDOStatement::fetchAll — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation says:

> [PDOStatement::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)
> — Fetches the next row from a result set

> [PDOStatement::fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows